# Form data from inputs not stored in database

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

So I have a form with bunch of inputs that I want to store in my table. But instead it just reloads the form and data from the inputs shows in url?

**My Form:**

```
<form class="ects">
    <div>
            <label for="name">Ime predmeta:</label>
            <input  type="text" id="name" 
            name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi ime predmeta">

            <label for="prof">Profesor</label>
            <input  type="text" id="prof" 
            name="prof" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi ime profesora">

            <label for="brk">Broj kredita:</label>
            <input type="number" id="brk" 
            name="brk" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj kredita">

            <label for="brcn">Broj casova nastave</label>
            <input type="number" id="brcn" 
            name="brcn" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova nastave">

            <label for="brcv">Broj casova vjezbi</label>
            <input type="number" id="brcv" 
            name="brcv" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova vjezbi">

            <label for="brcl">Broj casova lab</label>
            <input type="number" id="brcl" 
            name="brcl" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova lab">

            <label for="brsr">Samostalni rad</label>
            <input type="number" id="brsr" 
            name="brsr" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova za samostalno ucenje">

            <button id="add_ects" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pošalji</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS file:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function submitEcts() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.ects').each(function () {
            var answer={};
            answer['name'] = $(this).find('input[name="name"]').val();
            //answer['prof'] = $(this).find('input[name="prof"]').val();
            answer['broj_kredita'] = $(this).find('input[name="brk"]').val();
            answer['br_c_nastave'] = $(this).find('input[name="brcn"]').val();
            answer['br_c_vjezbi'] = $(this).find('input[name="brcv"]').val();
            answer['br_c_lab'] = $(this).find('input[name="brcl"]').val();
            answer['samostalni_rad'] = $(this).find('input[name="brsr"]').val();
            // console.log(answer);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/predmeti/"+subjectId+"/ects_submit",
                data: answer,
                success: function(data) {
                    window.location.href = "/profil";
                },
            });
        });
    }
    $('#add_ects').click(submitEcts);
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store($subject_id, Request $request)
    {
        $subject=Subject::find($subject_id);
        $validated=$request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'broj_kredita'=>'required',
            'br_c_nastave'=>'required',
            'br_c_vjezbi'=>'required',
            'br_c_lab'=>'required',
            'samostalni_rad'=>'required'
        ]);
        $validated['subject_id']=$subject_id;
        $validated['teacher_id']=$subject->teachers()->where('subject_id', $subject_id)->first()->id;
        return Ects::create($validated);
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/predmeti/{subject}/ects', 'EctsController@create');
Route::post('predmeti/{subject}/ects_submit', 'EctsController@store');
```

**Table:**

```
 Schema::create('ects', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->bigIncrements('id');
     $table->unsignedInteger('samostalni_rad');
     $table->unsignedInteger('br_c_nastave');
     $table->unsignedInteger('br_c_vjezbi');
     $table->unsignedInteger('br_c_lab');
     $table->unsignedInteger('broj_kredita');
     $table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->unsignedBigInteger('teacher_id');
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects');
     $table->foreign('teacher_id')->references('id')->on('teachers');
 });
```

I really don't know why it won't work. I had some forms with inputs before but they used to work somehow. This is the first time that the data are shown in url and I rally have no idea why this issue is about. Sorry for the long code, but most of the view file is same.

Comment: What is the response from your AJAX call? Have you checked if your controller is being reached?

Comment: You need to prevent default event of the submit button click...or change it to type=button.

Comment: How I can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="ects" method="post" action="#">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Ime predmeta:</label>
        <input  type="text" id="name" 
        name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi ime predmeta">

        <label for="prof">Profesor</label>
        <input  type="text" id="prof" 
        name="prof" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi ime profesora">

        <label for="brk">Broj kredita:</label>
        <input type="number" id="brk" 
        name="brk" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj kredita">

        <label for="brcn">Broj casova nastave</label>
        <input type="number" id="brcn" 
        name="brcn" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova nastave">

        <label for="brcv">Broj casova vjezbi</label>
        <input type="number" id="brcv" 
        name="brcv" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova vjezbi">

        <label for="brcl">Broj casova lab</label>
        <input type="number" id="brcl" 
        name="brcl" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova lab">

        <label for="brsr">Samostalni rad</label>
        <input type="number" id="brsr" 
        name="brsr" class="form-control" placeholder="Unesi broj casova za samostalno ucenje">

        <button id="add_ects" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pošalji</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS File:

```
    $('.ects').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/ects/"+subjectId+"/submit",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success:function(data) {
                    window.location.href = "/profil";

                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("Oops! Unfortunately the attempt was not successful!");
                }

            }
        );

    });
```

Try this. I have changed your JS file to lesson for form submission and prevent the default submission and instead use our ajax submission.

Comment: I made a mistake in ajax. My url was wrong. But now I'm getting an error for `$validated['teacher_id']=$subject->teachers()->where('subject_id', $subject_id)->first()->id;`. It says I'm trying to get the property of non-object.

Comment: Do you get the error after form submission in the controller?

Comment: Yes, when I try to submit the form.

Comment: I put the wrong data in my table so it what I tried to get didn't exist. Thank you and sorry for the troubles.

Comment: Try this : $validated['teacher_id'] = Teachers::where('subject_id', $subject_id)->first()->id; Don't forget to add the name space at the top of the controller like: use App\Teachers.